# The info icons in the left sidebar on Stack Overflow are misaligned

Tags: bug, design, sidebar

In the left sidebar on Stack Overflow, the info icons ([image: info icon]) next to the Teams and Collectives headings are misaligned:

[image: info icon alignment]

Comment: Literally unplayable

Comment: I am upvoting this in part because [they *are* aligned if you're in a Team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC5KV.png)...which I'm guessing most or all of the staff are, so it's unlikely that this would get noticed.

Comment: They're aligned in the fifth dimension though... Jeez, how unwelcoming to our different-dimensionally-attuned brethren.

Comment: The hover effect is also not aligned, and functions differently. The i next to TEAMS becomes lighter, and COLLECTIVES does nothing, when hovering over it.